# Find $U^{\dagger}$ for a quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm really lost at this:

Let q be the quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by
$q(x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1x_2 + 2x_1x_3 + x_3^2$.
Find an invertible linear operator U on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
$(U^{\dagger}q) (x_1, x_2, x_3) = x_1^2-x_2^2 + x_3^2$.

$(U^{\dagger}q)(x_1, x_2, x_3) = q(U(x_1, x_2, x_3))$. I'm guessing that $U^{\dagger}$ is like the pseudoinverse

Any advices?

Answer (score 1):

The matrix identity that follows, divided through by $2,$ says
$$  (x+z)^2 - \left(x - \frac{y}{2} \right)^2 + \frac{1}{4} y^2 = z^2 + 2 zx + xy $$
This can be revised quickly to 
$$  (x+z)^2 - \left(x - \frac{y}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{y}{2} \right)^2 = z^2 + 2 zx + xy $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 &  - 1 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Then my U is H, right?

Comment: @Bayesianguy, no, $U$ is $Q.$ The symmetric matrix $H$ is the Hessian of second partial derivatives of the quadratic form, which I wrote with variables $x,y,z$

Comment: oh I see, sorry. Thank you. I got lost with this problem.

Comment: How did you come up with that quadratic form at the beginning?